# Adding Multiple users from .CSV via batch file

Tags: windows-7, batch, csv

I wrote the following in a batch file

```
start cmd.exe /k net user test1 1qaz2wsx!QAZ@WSX /add /y
```

But I have to add a large number of users and passwords.

I have them all in an excel file, is there anyway for it to look at the CSV and do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the list in Excel, just use Excel to generate the batch file.

You should have a column for the user name and one for the password. Then create a formula like:

```
=CONCATENATE("start cmd.exe /k net user ",A2," ",B2," /add /y")
```

Then you can copy the contents of the resulting column to a new batch file and run it.

[image]